# IF loop with 2 inputs

Tags: python, if-statement

I am having trouble making an `if` loop with 2 inputs.

The idea of the code is to output:

- 1 if 'RSI' > 50 and 'MACD' > 0
- -1 if 'RSI' < 50 and 'MACD' < 0
- 0 for all other possible combinations.

Then add the resulting `Position` column to the dataframe.
RSI and MACD are calculated using the `ta` python library

When I try the code below I get the error:

> Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

[image: The code I tried]

Comment: use `or` not `|`. post code in question not an image

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the logical "or" operator not bitwise '|'.

if df['RSI'] > 50 or df['MACD'] < 100:

Comment: yes but I want them both to be true at the same time when being assigned

Comment: then use logical "and"